# SWF in PDF to process any data

Tags: pdf, postscript

How can I insert (using postscript) into my pdf-file a swf-file that it (flash) can processes other data from my pdf-file?

Comment: Although postscript is a programming language that supports file I/O, I find difficult to believe that you want to write a program in postscript that generates a PDF. Maybe you wanted to say ghostscript?

Answer (score 2):

Flash content inside a PDF file won't be able to 'process data from the PDF file'.

You can't (easily) insert content into a PDF file using PostScript. Although it is a programming language, the task makes my mind boggle.

If you are trying to add somethign to a PDF file using Ghostscript (as the commenter yms above suggested) the short answer is that you can't. The longer answer is that you *might* be able to, with some PostScript programming, but you haven't supplied enough information to tell. And it still wouldn't be able to 'process other data form the PDF file'